# Input function in Python is not able to take my input/text/answer in the output section

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Everything in my python exercise is doing great except the input function. it goes well till the halfway and shows my string which I've written in the program, but in the output area of VScode, it is not able to take my string or my input. the cursor or the text insertion bar which blinks when you type something does not blink in my case, instead it stands still and neither it blinks and nor lets me type. idk what the problem is. I've already re-typed, re-checked and spell checked over a hundred times but nothing is working.

as you can see below, in my output, it is not letting me type anything after showing the string "what is your name?"

```
#my input:
name= input("what is your name?") 
print("hello" + name )
```

my output:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\shreyash dahiwale\Desktop\python development\python.py" what is your name?
```

I have also restarted VScode and checked if there's anything wrong with my extensions but nothing is working.